# Django REST: getting serializer model field's default value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Using Django and REST for my project. At some point I need to access serializer model's field default value (since REST doesn't set default values). The code looks like this:

```
# try to get default from model, if it is not set then try to get default from serializer
default = serializer.Meta.model._meta.get_field(input_instance.field_name).default
```

I think this is ugly.

Is there any way to shorten this expression?

Comment: do you need it for validation in serializer `create` method? Why don't you just skip it, it should save default value.

Comment: Could you edit the post so I can change my vote to a positive one ?

Comment: @Linovia yes, I can edit my post - what exactly to change?

Comment: let's fix the exprassion -> expression typo :p